# Recompose and Apollo Query

Tags: apollo, recompose

Is it possible to use Recompose for the Query component of `react-apollo`?

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/queries.html#basic

I was thinking of something like this:

```
const props = {component:"Query", query: gql(ListResults), children: ViewResults};
export default withProps(props)(componentFromProp('component'))
```

Comment: I'm not sure your question has enough detail to receive the help you need. It doesn't seem like componentFromProps is what you're looking for. It was originally intended for visually rendering components with similar styling.
https://twitter.com/acdlite/status/662127795112308736?lang=en  The Query component from Apollo needs to have a query= prop.  No other component needs that prop so defining a generic version doesn't seem to make sense.  That being said I'm certain I don't fully understand what you're trying to do. :-D

Comment: What I want to do is define the components and props in a DynamoDB table, with GraphQL sitting in front of it. If I want to change an anchor link to a button, I can do it without updating the codebase. So the app will query first on load, get the components, props, and build to user, leveraging client side data.

If you want to help, I can pay and give Github and AWS.

Answer (score 1):

You can compose in a query instead of using the Query component.

Using the example from the link you posted.

```
import { compose } from 'recompose';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';

const Dogs = ({ data, onDogSelected }) => (
  <select name="dog" onChange={onDogSelected}>
    {data.dogs.map(dog => (
      <option key={dog.id} value={dog.breed}>
        {dog.breed}
      </option>
    ))}
  </select>
);

const GET_DOGS = gql`
  {
    dogs {
      id
      breed
    }
  }
`;

const getDogsQuery = graphql(GET_DOGS, {
  options: props => ({
    fetchPolicy: props.fetchPolicy // example of passing to the query from props.
  })
});

export default compose(getDogsQuery)(Dogs);  // { data } is now a prop with the query results.
```

Comment: Thank you! I need to review this more. To clarify, my goal is to have something like this in DynamoDB: {component:"Query", query: gql(ListResults), children: ViewResults}